Choosing mixing parameter in zero-one inflated beta
I am dealing with a problem in which I need to model (independent) population proportions ($p$) based on sample proportion ($f$) of size $n$. I chose the beta distribution for this:
$$ p \sim Beta[fn,(1-f)n]$$
Sometimes, I observed the sample proportion is equal to 1 or 0. For these cases the beta distribution always return 0 or 1, hence, these cases are not well accommodated into the model. To fix this, I decided to include Jeffreys' prior (adding 0.5 to the sample counts). However, there is still a chance of a population proportion equal to 0 (or 1) being the cause of a 0 (or 1) in the sample proportion. I have read about this topic and found the zero-one inflated beta models (e.g., for $f=1$):
$$ p \sim \omega + (1-\omega)Beta(n+0.5,0.5) $$
My question is, how to choose the mixing parameter $\omega$? Could you please give some insights whether my thinking is correct?
